# Spring boot - Bower Json - Whitelabel error page

Tags: javascript, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bower

I have used a dependency from my bower.json file

```
 {
  "name": "bower",
  "description": "This is a Spring Boot Application",
  "main": "index.html",
  "authors": [
    "Mark Lee S. Castillo <castillolee@yahoo.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.7",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.4",
    "angular-local-storage": "0.2.2",
    "angular-moment": "0.10.3",
    "angular-filter": "0.5.17",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.4.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "selectize": "0.12.1",
    "ui-select": "angular-ui-select#0.13.2",
    "ng-file-upload": "6.0.4",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "jspdf": "jsPDF-html2canvas#^1.2.61",
    "html2canvas": "0.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive": "0.1.3"
  }
}
```

to my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  <href
  ="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spring Boot Application</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a whitelabel error page when I add the `href` line under the title, but when I remove it, it works fine. And this is a new project which I created.

This is the controller for my index.html

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class springbootapplicationController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcomeController(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("welcome", "Spring boot application");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I am using Spring boot and this is my dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springbootapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>springbootapplication</name>
  <description>Spring Project</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I cant find which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is thymeleaf telling you that you got some invalid XHTML there.
Thymeleaf is **XML**, so you MUST close all your elements.
Also, you have an invalid leading '<' before the href attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
        <link 
            rel="stylesheet" 
            type="text/css"
            href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Spring Boot Application</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I should add that since this is Thymeleaf you are using, you should probably add in the schema reference.
The Template will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
    <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css"
        th:href="@{/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Spring Boot Application</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```